# Connection Logint to dashboard (Not detect the passwords)

Tags: javascript, php, css

Please check my code and tell me how to make it when click submits button, it goes to a dashboard page. but it does not work. Help.. I think functions not working. I can't figure out what is the problem. I already create my database and I added details in that database.

(I add database and) I will attach GitHub link too. Please check if you have time.

https://github.com/Dushan26/my_assignment.git

```
<?php  


$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="project_db";

$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysqli_select_db($con, 'project_db') or die(mysqli_error($con));

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    
    $uname=$_POST['txtUsername'];
    $password=$_POST['txtPassword'];
    
    $sql="select * from user where email='".$uname."'AND password='".$password."' limit 1";
    
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1){
        echo " You Have Successfully Logged in";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo " You Have Entered Incorrect Password";
        exit();
    }
        
}
?>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Online class</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <style>
            body{
                width: 100%;
                height: 400px;
                background-image:url(../assets/img/online-class.png);
                background-size: cover;
            }</style>

        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><!--row 01-->
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-5 mx-auto"><!--row 02-->
                    <div class="card my-5"> <!-- card-->
                        <div class="card-body"><!--card body-->
                        
                            <h5 class="text-center my-2"><b>:::LOGIN:::</h5></b><br>
                        <form class="form" action="" role="form" method="POST">
                            
                            <div clss="my-5" id="divEmail"><!--txtusername-->
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="txtUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                            </div><!--end oftxtusername--><br>
                            
                            <div clss="my-5" id="divPassword"><!-- password-->
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                            </div><!--end of password--><br>
                            
                            <div clss="my-4"><!-- button-->
                            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block text-uppercase col-12">Submit</button>
                            </div><!--end of button-->
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            <hr class="my-4"><h6>Enter Your Email & Password</h6>
                        
                        
                        </form><!--end of form-->
                    
                    
                </div><!--end of card body-->
                </div><!--end of card-->
            </div><!--end row 02-->
        
        </div><!--end of row 01-->
    </div><!--end of container-->
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your submit button is a type of a "submit". when it is inside a form and clicked, by default it submit the form regardless of your click function.

you can change the button type to "button" or change the click function to stop the form submit

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Still does not work. So, I add PHP code on the top. Connecting database and checking usernames and passwords. 

my table name is "user" and there are two columns "email" and "password" (I added it in code)